# Automated incremental backups from Plesk on Centos to Amazon S3

Tags: backup, centos, amazon-s3

I've done a far bit of research on this via Google and there seems to be quite a few ways of possibly doing this.

I'm looking to incrementally backup new and updated files in two directories on my Plesk run Centos 5.2 server: /backups and /var/www/vhosts (preferable only httdocs within each vhost)

Has anyone got some great feedback from using the various solutions - seems to be various Java, Perl and Ruby based solutions out there.

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/) It offer incremental backup, scp transfer for more security and backup to Amazon S3.

There is some other solutions but they are out of price if you only have one server.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Duplicity earlier - will have to check it's needs and functions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on article about backing up an Plesk server on Amazon S3: http://sandbox.frontline.ro/2008/10/31/plesk-backup-to-amazon-s3-testing-phase
As today, I think JungleDisk is the most reliable solution for mounting an S3 bucket.

I'll update my blog with some info about my implementation with JungleDisk.